# How to use SmsManager.importMultimediaMessage()? How to import MMS in Android's database?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contentresolver, smsmanager, android-mms

So, I'm building an app to copy all my messages (AND mms, WITH attachments) from iOS (iTunes backup) to Android Pie (OxygenOS).

I went through Android's [SmsManager.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/SmsManager.java#L1623) file, and I noticed two methods:

- `importTextMessage(...)` does the job perfectly for SMS!!
- `importMultimediaMessage(...)`, hum.. MMS is a big deal.

Can someone explain me how to use `importMultimediaMessage`?
What are the first 2 params?

I wish I could just import the attachments (`byte[]`) and somehow, link it to a message..

---

PS: These 2 methods are part of internal APIs, and thus, they are not well documented.
To use it in a project, we have to:

- use a modified version of android.jar (see version 28 here [github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api](https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api/tree/master/android-28))
- Run the following command from the computer

  ```
  adb shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_pre_p_apps  1
  adb shell settings put global hidden_api_policy_p_apps 1
  ```

  according to [developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces)

---

PS2: For those wondering why I'm using internal APIs, I will not publish this app. It's just for personal purposes. I'll probably delete it after all my Message restored. That's why I feel free to use Android's internal APIs.

---

PS3: I also tried this accepted answer ([stackoverflow.com/a/15224716/2559851](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224716/2559851)), but I don't know why, the `res` variable is always null here

```
Uri res = context.getContentResolver().insert(partUri, mmsPartValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself, I end up not using `importMultimediaMessage()`.

If you want a working project, see here https://github.com/let-aurn/iosmessagetoandroid.